# C# ToCharArray does not work with char*

Tags: c#, string, pointers, arrays

I have the following struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
unsafe public struct Attributes
{

    public OrderCommand Command { get; set; }

    public int RefID { get; set; }

    public fixed char MarketSymbol[30];
}
```

Now, I want to write characters to the field MarketSymbol:

```
string symbol = "test";
Attributes.MarketSymbol = symbol.ToCharArray();
```

The compiler throws an error, saying its unable to convert from char[] to char*.
How do I have to write this?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185269/how-to-convert-fixed-byte-char100-to-managed-char-in-c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct Attributes
{
    public OrderCommand Command { get; set; }
    public int RefID { get; set; }
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 30)]
    public string MarketSymbol;
}
```

Watch out for pack = 1, it is quite unusual.  And good odds for CharSet.Ansi if this interops with C code.

Comment: This does not work out. Later I marshal this structure to a Pointer with Marshal.StructureToPtr(myAttributes, Ptr, false); All other fields are doing good, except this string.

Comment: I have no idea what "does not work out" might mean.  Marshal.StructureToPtr has no trouble with a declaration like this.  Be explicit about what you see going wrong.  And note my comment about CharSet.